# Connecting to Openshift WebSocket issue

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to make my OpenShift Node.js app working, but the WS connection is not working. Client error is: connection refused.
Client side factory service:

```
var dataStream = $websocket(localStorageService.get('wsUrl'))

dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
    var call = JSON.parse(message.data)
    if (fnMap[call.fn]) {
        fnMap[call.fn](call.event, call.data)
    }

})

dataStream.onError(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
})

dataStream.onClose(function(event){
    console.log('event: ' + JSON.stringify(event))
})

var fnMap = {
    "broadcastResult": function(event, data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(event, data)
    }
}
var methods = {
    callFn: function(paramJSON) {
        dataStream.send(JSON.stringify(paramJSON));
    }
}
return methods
```

I'm trying to connect on the following URL: ws://myapp-myname.rhcloud.com:8000

Could you please help?

Thank you in advance,
Csaba

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to make sure the websocket library, `ws`, is installed by declaring it in the dependencies section of your `package.json` and then doing another `git push`.

Otherwise, try the example provided in the openshift blog: https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/

Specifically:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://myapp-myname.rhcloud.com:8000");
websocket.onopen = function(event) {
  // The connection was opened
  console.log(event)
}; 
websocket.onclose = function(event) { 
  // The connection was closed
  console.log(event)
}; 
websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  // New message arrived
  message = event.data
  console.log(event)
}; 
websocket.onerror = function(event) { 
  // There was an error with your WebSocket
  console.log(event)
};
```

The above at least might help point you toward a specific part of your code that's not working. Or, if the example isn't even working, it could be possibly something wrong with your cartridge, and you could try reaching out to RedHat's support.